# Document is missing mandatory uniqueKey field: id

Tags: solr

I am getting this error when trying to add a document to Solr (7.7.2)

Here is a minimized document that produces the error

```
{
  "add": {
    "doc": {
      "id": "DOC1",
      "deleted": true
    }
  }
}
```

and a minimized schema to go along with it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema name="Master" version="1.6">
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
    <fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"/>

    <field name="deleted" type="boolean" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="id" type="string" required="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    
    <!-- ignore all other fields -->
    <dynamicField name="*" type="ignored"/>

</schema>
```

When I submit just the document

```
{
 "id": "DOC1",
 "deleted": true
}
```

then it works but I want to submit it along with other documents/commands.

I understand what the message means, that I am trying to submit a document without the required field "id", but what I'm submitting **has** that field so I don't understand why I'm getting the error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you submiting the document? Through the admin web page? through curl?

Comment: I am submitting through the Admin UI under Documents and choosing JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if the Admin UI does not support the format that you are using, [the documentation](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_9/documents-screen.html) is not very clear about it.

You can try using cURL. Save your JSON to a file, say "sample.json" and the following command should do it:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@sample.json" http://localhost:8983/solr/your-solr-core/update?commit=true
```

Comment: Huh, submitting the same thing through cURL works.  Thanks a lot!  I will have to remember that the Admin UI doesn't support that format - I'd think it would just post what it's given.